# Eclipse Editor: Remove white icons (mouse wheel and arrows)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

I just installed the current eclipse application and noticed two strange things in the Editor.

1. When I move to the scrollbar of the Editor it shows me a mouse wheel icon.
2. On the bottom right it shows me 2 arrow icons.

[image]

How do I disable those?

Answer (score 1):

This is not added by Eclipse. Likely a feature of your mouse driver. Look for relevant settings in the mouse control panel.

Comment: This is wired since I have this mouse for about 5 years now and never saw those icons before. I will check once I get back to the mouse. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: So I unechekd all my mouse settings and still nothing. I'm sure it's an eclipse feature, since I can drag and drop the arrows around in the editor modus. This is starting to drive me nuts... QHwn i click and drag the scrollbars the icosn disapear. It's like a hint for people that this is a scrollbar ...

Comment: If you can't get your mouse driver to behave, I recommend contacting the manufacturer or uninstalling the driver. You don't need a custom driver for basic mouse operations and more often then not they are poorly written and just get in the way.